# How to check if a new user logged in?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase authentication to create users and log in.Is there any way to see if a new user logged in,different from the last one, on the same device?I'm trying to delete the local database if so.

Comment: Sure, just store the UID of the user somewhere.  When a sign-in occurs, compare the new UID with the prior UID, and decide what you want to do if they're different.

Comment: You could save the UID of the logged in user in sharedPreference, then set up a AuthStateListener where if user found- check if that matches with what's saved in sharedPref- if they match do nothing, if they don't- perform whatever cleanup you want + update sharedPref key to have new uid stored

Comment: It worked with storing the UID in sharedPreference and then making the check.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution to this problem would be to use an attribute that is unique to every user; that is the user's **UID** (from FirebaseAuth).

Save this in a reliable storage like SharedPreferences. When a user logs in, simply compare the UID of the user with the one you have saved. If they match, it's the same user.

This is how you get the user UID:

```
val mAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
val uid: String = mAuth.uid!! //UID
```

**PS**: If a user's UID doesn't match with the saved one after log in, remember to update the saved version.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It worked with storing the UID in sharedPreference and then making the check.Thanks!